# Populate Gridview Using Web Services in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, datagridview

I have make one webserive which have code of this

```
static SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Connection"].ToString());

[WebMethod]
public DataSet SQLBranchMaster() {

    String Load = "SELECT * FROM BranchMaster";
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(Load,conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapt.Fill(ds);
    conn.Close();
    return ds;

}
```

now on windows forms my code is

```
  dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

// Service is my Webserive class name
// myservice is my reference added in the Winforms

myservice.Service test = new myservice.Service();
dataGridView1.DataSource = test.SQLBranchMaster();
```

how to do now ?
nothing shown when i run the form

Comment: Isn't your webservice supposed to return some sort of JSON or XML file serialized? How does it return a dataset over the web?

Comment: try adding `Controls.Add(dataGridView1);` after you have set the datasource. Why are you delcaring you grid at runtime?

Comment: Are you calling 'dataGridView1.DataBind()' after setting the datasource property?

Comment: @barc0de is it not requerid in WinForms

Comment: @jens kloster -- u r right not required...now what to do ?

Comment: @HiralBhimani You need to show more code. are the gridview present at design time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning dataset from service method so, bind a table to DataGridview
So, make sure DataGridview is added to forms controls collection correctly (better to drag and drop control at form UI manually) and then use following way to bind it.

```
myservice.Service test = new myservice.Service();
DataSet ds= test.SQLBranchMaster();

if (ds.Tables.count > 0)
{
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: hey grt...job ...done it..
why write "ds.tables[0]" ?
not only "ds"

Comment: Since a dataset may have many tables so, how would a control know to which table need to be bound? that's why need to specify specific table. In your case, there only one table which will always be at 0 Index in dataset